# UIImage/UIView Animation cycles images too fast, need to slow it down

Tags: ios, xcode

I've got an Image Slideshow animation in my app, but as standard it seems to go ridiculously fast, I'm not sure why this is the default speed. But anyway I need a way of slowing it down. The speed of the animation itself is fine, but each image doesn't stay on the screen for long enough at all! Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
- (void)animateImages
{
static int count = 0;
NSArray *animationImages =@[[UIImage imageNamed:@"blur_edges.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"blur_edges2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"blur_edges3.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"blur_edges4.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"slide8.png"]];
UIImage *image =
[animationImages objectAtIndex:(count % [animationImages count])];
[UIView transitionWithView:_imView
                  duration:1.5
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    _imView.image = image;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [self animateImages];
                    count++;
                }];
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should use a global variable here.

Comment: what would you recommend I change it to? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
    UIImageView * _imView ;
}
@end

@implementation MyObject

const NSTimeInterval kTimeBetweenSlides = 3.0 ;

-(void)nextImageTimerFired:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    NSEnumerator * enumerator = [ timer userInfo ] ;
    [ self nextImage:enumerator ] ;
}

-(void)nextImage:(NSEnumerator*)enumerator
{
    UIImage * nextImage = [ enumerator nextObject ] ;
    if ( nextImage != nil )
    {
        [UIView transitionWithView:_imView duration:1.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
            _imView.image = nextImage;
        } completion:nil ];
        [ NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kTimeBetweenSlides target:self selector:@selector( nextImageTimerFired: ) userInfo:enumerator repeats:NO ] ;
    }
}

-(void)animateImages
{
    NSArray * images = @[
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"blur_edges.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"blur_edges2.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"blur_edges3.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"blur_edges4.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"slide8.png"]
                 ] ;

    NSEnumerator * enumerator = [ images objectEnumerator ] ;
    [ self nextImage:enumerator ] ;
}

@end
```

This creates an enumerator you can use to walk through your array of images. We kick off the process by calling *-nextImage:*. This pulls the next image from the enumerator, then schedules a timer to call us after a delay. The timer handler calls *-nextImage:* again to display the next image. The process repeats until the enumerator is empty.

You could even use an array of images names instead of image objects, depending how large your images are.

Comment: I will try it now and get back to you!

Comment: I am getting 'use of undeclared identifier' for the nextImageTimerFired. I Have got 
    @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
    { 
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
    NSTimer *nextImageTimerFired;
    }
in the h. file, what am I doing wrong? Sorry massive noob

Comment: you left our the important part... which identifier is undefined? Don't add `NSTimer * nextImageTimerFired` to your .h file. In fact, you don't need to declare ivars in most cases any more.

Comment: I just get 'use of undeclared identifier 'nextImageTimerFired'', sorry but I don't even know how to fix that....

Comment: I changed my answer since I first posted it... `_imView.image = image` should be `_imView.image = nextImage`

Comment: (One problem was missing ';')

Comment: for some reason the 
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; 
part is given me errors now. No visible interface for NSObject

Comment: I've just got rid of the errors now, but when I run the app I just get a blank space where the slideshow should be

Comment: Did your images load? is images ≠ nil? Did you set _imView to a UIImageView? Did you add _imView to a superview? You will have to learn to use the debugger...

Comment: Post your project somewhere?

Comment: Sorry but I think I'm in way over my head haha! Where do people normally post their projects? can you share files on here? Thanks a lot for all this help

Comment: Well I can't help you too much. You could check it in to github. You should probably find someone that knows about Obj-C

Comment: I may just have to leave it. It's the last thing I need to get working on the app and its been bugging the hell out of me but I hand it over on wednesday and need to do write up so may just have to deal with it!

Thanks a lot though

Answer (score 0):

Increase your duration time from more than 1.5 to your perfect matching speed.

Comment: tried that, that actually increases the time of the animation, so the photo stays up for just as long, but they the animation between the images takes longer, so you just end up with a blur